# Confusion with sublists

Tags: lisp

I ran over an example of a problem which should determine the list of all non-numeric atoms at any level in a non-linear list.

```
   (Defun Lis(L)
      (Cond
        ((Null L) Nil)
        ((Not (Numberp (Car L))) (Cons (Car L) (Lis (Cdr L))))
        ((Atom (Car L)) (Lis (Cdr L)))
        (T (Append (Lis (Car L)) (Lis (Cdr L))))
    ))
```

I took an example, `(Lis '(1 A ((B) 6) (2 (C 3)) D 4))` which should return `(A B C D)`
Now I don't understand how can the list be created when the 3rd element of the list is evaluated `((B) 6)`.It will enter on the 2nd branch and do the `cons`?But that isn't constructing the new list with `((B) 6)`?When will it enter on the last branch? I'm a little confused of how this algorithm works,can somebody make it clear for me?

Comment: When you say it _should_ return `(A B C D)` are you saying that because you executed it by hand or did you really evaluate your expression in a Lisp interpreter?

Comment: That the result written in the book where I found it.

Comment: The brackets are all wrong in that code, so it can't work. It also seems to have the bug you mention. If it's from a book, there's an error in the book. (And what book writes Lisp in that style?)

Comment: Yep, your hunch about `((B) 6)` is almost certainly correct.  Books can be wrong.  You've got to try it in a real interpreter.  Then you can try fixing it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code works fine if you "invert" the 2 middle tests:

```
(defun lis(L)
  (cond
   ((null L)          nil)
   ((numberp (car L)) (lis (cdr L)))
   ((atom (car L))    (cons (car L) (lis (cdr L))))
   (t                 (append (lis (car L)) (lis (cdr L))))))
```

because `(not (numberp (car L)))` is also true for lists so in the initial version the code never recurses down into a sublist.

Answer (score 1):

I would write it as:

```
(defun tree-keep-if (predicate tree)
  "Returns the list of all non-numeric atoms at any level in a cons tree."
  (mapcan (lambda (item)
            (cond ((consp item)             (tree-keep-if predicate item))
                  ((funcall predicate item) (list item))
                  ((atom item)              nil)))
          tree))
```

Using it:

```
CL-USER > (tree-keep-if (complement #'numberp) '(1 A ((B) 6) (2 (C 3)) D 4))
(A B C D)
```

A more sophisticated version might remove the recursion to not be limited by stack size.